# Preserving text size with `grid.arrange`

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Problem

I have 4 graphs that I want to display using `grid.arrange()`. When I display them individually, they look like this:

[image]

But when I use `grid.arrange()`, they become distorted

[image]

with them individually looking like

[image]

Specific Issues:

1. The x-axis labels do not scale and overlap, making them unreadable.
2. The subtitles get cutoff.

#### Goal

I want to reproduce each plot exactly like the first ideal case in a grid with `grid.arrange()`. One possible way might be to convert each plot to an image and then use `grid.arrange()` but I don't know how to do this.

#### Reproducible Example

Below is an example reproducible code that shows the problem I am having.

```
p1 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl = 4), aes(wt, mpg, colour = cyl)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE", subtitle = "-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-") +theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 
p2 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl = 4), aes(wt, mpg, colour = cyl)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE-TITLE", subtitle = "-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-subtitle-") +theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Are you viewing the plots in the small panel in RStudio? Would the *distortion* change when you export or zoom out the plot? I do not see such distortion with reproducible example. Also add '\n' in titles to break lines.

Comment: I am exporting them using R Markdown into a PDF, which I need because it's a report. 

The \n suggestion is a good idea for the subtitles. But the x-axis part is still an issue. 

Also, modifying graphs this way seems inefficient. Why can't I scale them like pictures?

Comment: Make sure you need to use `grid.arrange`. I often see folk using it when`facet_wrap` would work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display those graphs individually they simply have more space. So, those are *natural* distortions and there are perhaps only three ways to solve that.

1. When exporting the combined graph, make it big enough. If the individual one looks good in 6x5 inches, then surely the combined one will look good in 12x10 inches.
2. Give correspondingly less space for the problematic parts: x-axis labels and the subtitle. For instance, use something like `element_text(size = 6)` for `plot.subtitle` and `axis.title.x`, add `\n` to the subtitles and even x-axis labels, try something like `element_text(angle = 30)` for the latter as well.
3. Get rid of something unnecessary. As @Richard Telford suggests in the comments, using `facet_wrap` should work better. That would be due to, e.g., not repeating the y-axis labels and, hence, giving more horizontal space.

Comment: @Stan Shunpike, I suspect that you might not like this solution, but the problem is that when you rescale the plot in R in one way or another, the text size remains the same. Your first plot is rectangular, while in the second one each individual plot is square with apparently smaller width and, hence, the text doesn't fit anymore.

Comment: This was an excellent solution. It works better than what I had proposed and the results are better than I imagined. Thanks!